# Combining Multiple Social Network Accounts

Tags: facebook, twitter, linkedin-api, social-networking, instagram

Is it possible (and secure) to show a list of your friends and people you follow from multiple social networking accounts (if you've connected yours)? Let's say I've connected my Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, and Instagram accounts, and I follow Joe Smith on all of those. What sort of logic would I use to consolidate Joe into a single entity with his accounts. For instance if I wanted to display him like so:

Joe Smith - Facebook | LinkedIn| Twitter | Instagram

How can I do this if people have different usernames, email addresses, display names, etc...? Is this even possible without having to display duplicate entries?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible, but as you mention, it would get tricky where people have different usernames on different social networks. Combining by email address would be your first port of call, and fairly straight forward, but after that your matching algorithm would need to get smarter (Should it match Joe Smith or Jane Smith to the LinkedIn 'J Smith' account??).